# R Storing Values from For Loop to Data Frame

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that has 2 arguments: column name and ranking number. The function will read a CSV file that has hospitals from every state. The function should return a data frame with the hospital name that was at the specified rank.

My solution has been to split the main CSV file by state, order each data frame by the desired column, loop through each state's data frame, grab the row (where row number = rank number), store each state's hospital name into a vector, then create a dataframe using the vector from the loop.

When I test each part of my function in the console, I am able to receive the results I need. However, when I run the function altogether, it isn't storing the hospital names as desired.

Here's what I have:

```
rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best") {
    outcomedf <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")

    #using this as a test
    outcomedf <- outcomedf[order(outcomedf[, 11], outcomedf[, 2]), ]


    #create empty vectors for hospital name and state
    hospital <- c()
    state <- c()

    #split the read dataframe
    splitdf <- split(outcomedf, outcomedf$State)

    #for loop through each split df
    for (i in 1:length(splitdf)) {
        #store the ranked hospital name into hospital vector
        hospital[i] <- as.character(splitdf[[i]][num, 2])
        #store the ranked hospital state into state vector
        state[i] <- as.character(splitdf[[i]][, 7])
    }

    #create a df with hospital and state
    rankdf <- data.frame(hospital, state)
    return(rankdf)
}
```

When I run the function altogether, I receive NA in my 'hospital' column, but when I run each part of the function individually, I am able to receive the desired hospital names. I'm a little confused as to why I am able to run each individual part of this function outside of the function and it returns the results I want, but not when I run the function as a whole. Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of `dput(head(outcomedf, 20))`?

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to Programming Assignment 3 in the Johns Hopkins University R Programming course on Coursera. As such, we can't provide a "corrected version" of the code because doing so would violate the Coursera Honor code.

When run with the default settings, your implementation of the `rankall()` function fails because when you use `num` in the extract operator there is no `["best",2]` row.  If you run your code as `head(rankall("heart attack",1))` it produces the following output.

```
> head(rankall("heart attack",1))
                              hospital state
1     PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER    AK
2             CRESTWOOD MEDICAL CENTER    AL
3              ARKANSAS HEART HOSPITAL    AR
4                 MAYO CLINIC HOSPITAL    AZ
5    GLENDALE ADVENTIST MEDICAL CENTER    CA
6 ST MARYS HOSPITAL AND MEDICAL CENTER    CO
```

To completely correct your function, you'll need to make the following changes.

1. Add code to sort the data by the desired `outcome` column: heart attack, heart failure, or pneumonia
2. Add code to handle the condition when a state does not have enough hospitals to return a valid result (i.e. the 43rd ranked hospital for pneumonia in Puerto Rico
3. Add code to handle "best" and "worst" as inputs to the `num` argument

Comment: Yea, I understand that part of the assignment; I excluded those parts because I think I have a good handle of the best/worst part of the function. 
The problem I have is that when I run each individual part of the function individually (in the global environment), I am able to get the correct results in the data frame. 
However, when I try to run the function altogether, the dataframe that is returned contains NA values (ie: not the same dataframe that I was able to produce in the global environment).

Comment: The problem seems to be in the for loop that 'hospital' is not storing all of the hospitals in the vector properly or it's not storing the 'hospital' vector correctly into the data frame.

Comment: @xpandamonium - I am able to get the function to generate valid output for multiple values of num, Therefore the problem must be with the way you are reading the raw data in your function.